# On adding Navigation List in ActionBar using Sherlock Library, Tabs hides in Android?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBar using Sherlock library. Implemented Tabs also in this app.

Now, when I am using the NavigationList in the ActionBar, I lost my Tab fragments. For using ListNavigation in the ActionBar I have used:

```
mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

& before this I was using `mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` for tabs but no list.

Now, I want to use both , `NavigationList` and `Tab Fragments`

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnNavigationListener {
    ActionBar mActionBar;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Getting a reference to action bar of this activity */
        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        /** Set tab navigation mode */
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        //mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, 
                R.array.locations, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);
        mActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);

        /** Getting a reference to ViewPager from the layout */
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        /** Getting a reference to FragmentManager */
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();      

        /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {              
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);             
            }

        };

        /** Setting the pageChange listner to the viewPager */
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

        /** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

        /** Setting the FragmentPagerAdapter object to the viewPager object */
        mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);

        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        /** Defining tab listener */
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {              
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            }
        };

        /** Creating Android Tab */
        Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Android")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.android)
                .setTabListener(tabListener);

        mActionBar.addTab(tab);

        /** Creating Apple Tab */
        tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Apple")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.apple)
                .setTabListener(tabListener); 
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);  


    }
}
```

MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;

    /** Constructor of the class */
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        switch(arg0){

            /** Android tab is selected */
            case 0:
                AndroidFragment androidFragment = new AndroidFragment();                
                data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
                androidFragment.setArguments(data);
                return androidFragment;

            /** Apple tab is selected */
            case 1:
                AppleFragment appleFragment = new AppleFragment();
                data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
                appleFragment.setArguments(data);
                return appleFragment;   
        }

        return null;
    }

    /** Returns the number of pages */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {     
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

And the other two classes:
1) `public class AppleFragment extends SherlockListFragment`

2) `public class AndroidFragment extends SherlockListFragment`

Please suggest me, why I am losing my Tabs on adding List to ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use both `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` and `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` at the same time. You can use just a navigation mode at a time.

Comment: you can't use both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of list navigation and tabs in the `ActionBar` is mutually exclusive, you just can use only one.

If you want to use both list and tabs, you have to use different implementation for at least one of them. For tabs you can use [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). Spinner in the `ActionBar` can be created several ways:

- use custom view to create the spinner
- use `actionLayout` or `actionViewClass` for a menu item
- use `ActionProvider` for a menu item

**Edit:** 
In your case the easiest adjustment is to use `ViewPagerIndicator` instead of `ActionBar` tabs. Changing list navigation requires more work. 
The web page of the `ViewPagerIndicator` project shows some example setup which you should take a look at. The project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) has many samples which shows how to use various setups of the library. I guess what you are looking for is `TabPageIndicator`, so take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsDefault.java) (notice that the tabs' titles are created in the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, you don't need `ActionBar.Tab` and `ActionBar.TabListener` anymore).

Comment: Can you please provide some example, how can I implement it in custom way.

Comment: I added some info about IMHO the easiest adjustment you should do.